# How to get Element node in transform of xml using s9api XQuery transformation

Tags: xquery, element, saxon

I am using saxon s9api to transform xml with XQuery. With below code it is possible but I'm getting XPathException.

The XQueryEvaluator expects Element node but I am not sure how to get Element from Document node.

I have tried to iterating and passing the children of the document.

```
// first java class
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
DocumentBuilder db = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode doc = db.build(new StreamSource(new 
StringReader(innerResponse.getBody())));

// second java class where new processor is created.
XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();
XQueryExecutable executable = 
compiler.compile(getXQueryFileAsString(interfaceId));
XQueryEvaluator query = executable.load();

query.setExternalVariable(new QName("result1"), ((XdmNode) doc));
XdmValue nodes = query.evaluate();


// XQuery
(:: pragma bea:global-element-parameter parameter="$result1" element="result" location="../XMLSchemas/myxsd.xsd" ::)
(:: pragma bea:global-element-return element="result" location="../XMLSchemas/anotherxsd.xsd" ::)

declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/somepath/XQueries/Result/";

declare function xf:Result($result1 as element(result),

// input xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<result>
        <code>OK</code>
        <somedata>
        ..
        </somedata>
</result>
```

Exception:

> XPTY0004: The required item type of the value of variable $result1 is element(Q{}result);
>   the supplied value doc() does not match. The supplied value is a document node
>   net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: The required item type of the value of variable $result1 is element(Q{}result); the supplied value doc() does not match. The supplied value is a document node
>     at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryEvaluator.evaluate(XQueryEvaluator.java:430)

Comment: Your XQuery code seems to declare a function with a parameter named $result1 typed as element(result), how does your input document look exactly, does it contain any element named result? Where, is that simply the root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `result` element is the outermost element of the document, and that you are using Saxon 9.9, use

```
doc.select(child("result")).asNode();
```

to get the `result` element.

You will need

```
import static net.sf.saxon.s9api.streams.Steps.child;
```

to access the `child()` method

Comment: Michael Kay's answer works well. 
Previously I had tried to iterate the doc (XdmNode) elements and get the first child.

    `XdmSequenceIterator<XdmNode> iter = doc.axisIterator(Axis.CHILD);
    if (iter.hasNext())
        return iter.next();`